# Getting stuck when trying to upload files to GitHub repository

Tags: git, github

I'm completely new to GitHub so I have some elementary questions. My university creates a repository for me in which I should often commit any changes made to my web app project. But I had already started working on my project so I already have some local files.

In the GitHub repository is an app folder, in which I would like to upload/commit (?) the whole folder I created locally with many files and folders in it.

I've read some info online, so I first cloned the repository locally, and then I pasted my project in the app folder. Then I ran `git add .` which, as far as I know, adds all the changes or new files. Then I ran `git push origin main` which deleted my whole repository and uploaded the local repository folder, but I can't open it or anything.

There is also the 'main' branch and the 'master' branch. The main branch remained intact.

I've read many tutorials online, but I feel like they don't really apply to me or I'm doing things wrong, so could somebody explain what I'm doing wrong and how I can maybe fix it?

Comment: GitHub has renamed the `master` branch with `main`. Sounds like your school created the repository from the GitHub website with the branch named `main` and as you might have created a git source control the old way, your branch name is `master`. What you probably should do is to rename your `master` branch `main` and push the changes to GitHub for them to be in sync with the repository.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you pulled the repository changes down before you added your local file changes, with `git add .` and then pushed. When you use `git add .`, git is going to add all of the diff'd files, and if you haven't pulled down the remote files git takes that as a file deletion. There are a couple of fixes I would suggest:

1. If most of the files you have changed are already in the repo: merge your `main` branch with the `master` branch - fix any problems with your code and add, commit and push your changes
2. Find out what files you want to checkout from the remote repo and use `git checkout <branch or pre-overwrite-commit-hash> file.txt` to manually get any files you want from another branch or commit that you haven't edited yet.